# Copying existing file into Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

When I save a file in SWP5.5 a copy is created in Texmaker. When I open the file in Texmaker it usually loads as untitled even though the title was saved in the correct format file-name.tex without spaces, punctuation, or accents. The code appears but PDF and QuickLoad commands will not function or give warnings such as File Not Found.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Unfortunately I have no idea what you are talking about, starting with wondering, what SWP5.5 might be. And without any code I wonder who might be able here to help you ... // Please provide more concrete information. Thanks.

Comment: To MS-SPO: SWP5.5 is a version of Scientific Workplace, a software product that produces LaTeX documents using drop-down menus or keystrokes for the math (so TeX commands are not needed). To display the code, the .tex file needs to be saved and opened on a TeX platform, such as Texmaker. That usually works but the QuickLoad and PDF functions usually don't.

Comment: Sorry, SWP has gone out of business and perhaps their macros are no longer recognized.